# Simple HTML DOM causes memory exhaustion when included

Tags: php, memory-leaks, simple-html-dom

I have a template with a couple of includes and use `Simple HTML DOM` for various tasks.

When I inlcude the library, on some pages I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 28672 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\aa\template.php on line
>   142

This is my php code in the template:

```
<?php
$currentFile = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$parts = Explode('/', $currentFile); 
$page = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
$parent = basename(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
$both = $parent.'/'.$page;
$content = $filename.".html";
$sidebar = $filename. "-sidebar.html";

?>
<?php include('dom.php'); ?>
<?php 

if (!isset($title)) {
$html = file_get_html($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/aa/content/'.$content);

$element = $html->find('h1'); 
if ($element) {
$titletag = $element[0]->plaintext . ' | about-berlin.com';
}

    }
else {
$titletag = $title; 
}
$html->__destruct();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The odd thing is I get the same memory error even when I only include the library like this, without any code using it:

```
<?php include('dom.php'); ?>
```

If I dont include it everything runs without an error.

How is it possible to get this error without even using the `file_get_html()` which seem to be responsible for most problems? What could I try to fix this problem without changing `php.ini`?

**EDIT**:

Some clarification. My templating works like this:

somepage.php is requested.
Inside is the following code:

```
<?php 
$path_parts = pathinfo(__FILE__);
$filename = $path_parts['filename'];

include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/aa/template.php');
?>
```

In the template the content file of the same name (somepage.php) is included from a folder called content.

Comment: What code is in line 142 of your template.php? First you should try to include_once or require_once the file, so it wont be double included.

Comment: line 142 is a closing li tag. However the dom.php gets included there, so maybe line 142 is inside it actually?

Comment: Do you call that script inside a loop? Where do you define the $content? Please update your first post and lets see some more code...

Comment: I updated my question, the script is not inside a loop, but the template gets included in the requested file. Inside the template the dom is included and the content

Comment: the problem only occurs in one of the folders but in none of my other folders... there seems to be something wrong with that folder ?!

Comment: Have you tried to check weather the folder really exists and can be found by your script? `if (!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/aa/content/'.$content)) { echo 'Failure: File ' . $content . ' not found!'; exit;}` before use the DOMLoader?

Comment: still the same. the folder exists for sure. if i remove the dom.php include everything works.

Comment: Also the Dom-Parser? So you will have had included it serveral times I think. Replace your include with include_once at all places you include it and replace require with require_once.

Comment: I only include it once. I changed to include_once and it works now! Many thanks for this tip. Pls post an answer so I may accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing your

```
include(…);
```

to

```
include_once(…);
```

will prevent your script from multi includes scripts. If you need a script to make it work you should use

```
require_once(…);
```

I think there is somewhere another include of your dom.php. Maybe in the script that includes the shown code.
Another thing is that you should remove closing php-tags that are followed from opening-php-tags to make the code more readable. Something like

```
?>
<?php
```

is not nessecary.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$html->clear(); 
unset($html);
```

the memory leak is due to a php5 circular reference memory leak

and

```
 ?>
<?php include('dom.php'); ?>
<?php
```

can be replaced with

```
include('dom.php');
```

just to keep things clean :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value memory_limit 64M
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I think the 128MB of allowed RAM should be enough for a script :)